# Developing a replication process

Tags: image

i've been developing a product which i would like to deploy to a few dozen raspi's and the issue is, once i develop a release, typically less than 500mb it is on a 4gb sd card and i can't find a procedure to compress it back to a iso image less than 4gb.

i have tried a few different tutorials but either i get an image that won't boot or not compressed enough to be beneficial.

does anyone have a process they would like to share for the generating of an ISO image, compressed and ready for deployment

Comment: You should explain better what you have tried beyond "a few different tutorials".   I know how to make an image that fits the content, but I am not going to bother explaining it only to hear, "Oh I tried that already...".